# Simple NodeJS Router Issues -- Misbehaving Case Statement?

Tags: javascript, node.js, router

I know that there are plenty of Node JS router frameworks out there, but I'm trying to start from square one and learning the concept rather than reuse code. In short, my extremely simple router is working part way but has some issues. Here is the code.

```
 function serverStart(urlRoute) {
    function onRequest(request, response) {
        var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
        console.log("Request received for " + pathname + ".");

        urlRoute(pathname, request, response);

        response.end();
    }

    http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
    console.log("Server has started." );
 }
```

Router code:

```
function urlRoute(pathname, req, res) {
        console.log(pathname)
    switch(pathname) {
        case '/':
            console.log("Request for path '/'");
            res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
            res.write("In Index!");
        case '/start':
            console.log("Request for path '/start'");
            res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
            res.write("In Start!");
        case '/foo':
            console.log("Request for path '/foo'");
            res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
            res.write("In Foo!");
    default: // Default code IS working
            console.log("404");
            res.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
            res.write("Default 404"); 
    }
}
```

The default and/or 404 section works fine, but the others do not. Basically, if I request the index page "/" all case statements fire, and similarly the next case fires itself and everything below it. So, "/foo" fires "foo" and writes out 404 to the console, but I don't get a 404 page (unless of course I use a bad URL altogether).

Trying to understand why the case doesn't seem to behave properly. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `break` statements between your `case` clauses. JavaScript `switch` statements borrow their behavior from C and other similar languages, and "fall-through" behavior is the way it's supposed to work (even though that may seem like a terrible idea).

Thus:

```
switch(pathname) {
    case '/':
        console.log("Request for path '/'");
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        res.write("In Index!");
        break;
    case '/start':
        console.log("Request for path '/start'");
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        res.write("In Start!");
        break;
    case '/foo':
        console.log("Request for path '/foo'");
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        res.write("In Foo!");
        break;
    default: // Default code IS working
        console.log("404");
        res.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        res.write("Default 404"); 
}
```

Comment: Perfect. That was it. Thank you. And yes, did not think the break was necessary!